# Inner join except for one case

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a following statistics table:

```
id | date | user_id | price | additional_price
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT month, sum(price), sum(additional_price)
FROM statistics s
INNER JOIN users u on s.user_id = u.id
AND u.confirmed = 1
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

The problem is that there are rows in this table where price is equal to `0`, but the additional_price is greater than `0`, where users are not confirmed, or don't exist anymore. I want to count them into the output sum. Something like:

```
SELECT t.month, sum(t.price), sum(t.additional_price)
FROM (

(SELECT month, sum(price), sum(additional_price)
FROM statistics s
INNER JOIN users u on s.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.confirmed = 1
AND s.price > 0
GROUP BY MONTH(date))
UNION
(SELECT month, sum(price), sum(additional_price)
FROM statistics s
WHERE price = 0
GROUP BY MONTH(date))

) AS t
GROUP BY MONTH(t.date);
```

It will work, that's the result I want to achieve. But the query is slow, it's big, and unmaintainable. The main issue I'm having with this is that I can't use relations on a table like that:

```
$statistics = Statistic::join('users');
$statisticsForZeroPrice = Statistic::forZeroPrice();
$result = DB::query()->fromSub($statistics->union($statisticsForZeroPrice), 't')
 ->with('user') // will not work 
 ->groupBy('t.date')
 ->get();
```

Is there a simpler solution to this issue?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  At a minimum, qualified column names would at least clarify where the columns are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want a `left join`.  From the limited information in your question, something like this:

```
SELECT month, sum(price), sum(additional_price)
FROM statistics s LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON s.user_id = u.id AND u.confirmed = 1
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

It is unclear which table should be first in the `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month, sum(price), sum(additional_price)
FROM statistics s
LEFT JOIN users u on s.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.confirmed = 1 OR price = 0
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
     SELECT month, sum(price), sum(additional_price) 
       FROM statistics s 
 INNER JOIN users u on s.user_id = u.id 
      WHERE (u.confirmed = 1 AND s.price > 0) OR (u.confirmed = 0 AND s.price = 0) 
   GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 unioned queries differ only in the conditions of the `WHERE` clause.
Why not combine them like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) month, SUM(price), SUM(additional_price)
FROM statistics s INNER JOIN users u 
ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE (u.confirmed = 1 AND s.price > 0) OR (s.price = 0)
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```